# get datatable raw id to another datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have an appointment list datatable and assign workers datatable, assign workers datatable has checkboxes for each row. Assign workers datatable is popup when clicking the assign button on the appointment list datatable.
What I want is, when the user clicks a checkbox on assign workers datatable, relevant appointment datatable row id display next to the checkbox. How can do this? I have not more experience with datatables.

appointment list datatable:

[image]

code of appointment list datatable:

```html
$('#appointment-datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '/get_appointment_data',
                columns: 
                    [
                      {
                        data: 'id', 
                        name: 'id'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'firstname', 
                        name: 'firstname'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'lastname', 
                        name: 'lastname'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'vehiclemodel', 
                        name: 'vehiclemodel'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'date', 
                        name: 'date',
                        searchable: true
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'time', 
                        name: 'time'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'payment_status', 
                        name: 'payment_status'
                      },
                      {
                        data: 'amount', 
                        name: 'amount'
                      },
                      {
                        data: null,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) 
                        {
                            let id = data['id']
                            return '<button id="mdButtonViewService" value="'+id+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">View Services</button>'       
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        data: null,
                        orderable: false,
                        render: function (data, type, full, meta) 
                        {
                            let id = data['id']
                            return '<button id="mdButtonAssign" value="'+id+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Assign</button> <button id="mdButtonDelete" value="'+id+'" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>'       
                        }
                      }
                    ]
              })
```

assign worker datatable:

[image]

code of assign worker datatable:

```html
              $('#assign-datatable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                ajax: '/get_freeEmp_data',
                lengthMenu: [5, 10, 20, 50, 100],
                columns: 
                        [
                          {
                            data: 'id', 
                            name: 'id'
                          },
                          {
                            data: 'name', 
                            name: 'name'
                          },
                          {
                            data: 'category', 
                            name: 'category'
                          },
                          {
                            data: null,
                            orderable: false,
                            render: function (data, type, full, meta,) 
                              {

                                let name = data['name']
                                let row_id = $('#assignBtn').val()
                                return '<input type="checkbox" id="emp_checkbox" value="'+name+'" name="emp[]"> <span class="badge badge-primary">'+row_id+'</span>'       
                              }
                          }
                        ] 
              })
```

Comment: Hi, if my answer still not answer your question just comment why, if it's answered please accept it. thank you.

Comment: i only want the row id. how can i do that?

Comment: `full.id` is the row id

Answer (score 0):

change `let id = data['id']` to  `let id = full.id`

`full` variable in your datatable render function is an object containing all data of your row including id,firstname,lastname,etc.